# How to connected Google Analytics 4 to Google Ads Campaign to track goals?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-ads, google-analytics-4

Trying to connect Google Analytics 4 (GA4) to my google ads account, but in the google ads campaign it only pulls the old, universal analytics properties (UA).

Is there a way for google ads to pull the GA4 data/goals?

To connect google analytics, I go to the `google ads campaign`, then `conversions -> get started`, but it only shows "`UA-...`" properties

[image]

[image]

I've successfully connected my GA4 property under `settings -> setup -> Linked accounts` but it doesn't seem to make any difference as it doesn't show up when I try to connect it with the ads campaign.

[image]

Comment: Odd. When I go to Conversions in Google Ads, I get a list of existing conversions and a button to add new ones. Clicking that button gives me four choices of type of conversion, the fourth of which is "Import", which then gives an option to import from UA or GA4, thus: https://imgur.com/a/RdaNlgM

Comment: @GeoffAtkins thanks. Based on your comment I went to "tools & settings" -> "measurement" -> "conversions" and I can see the same screen from you screenshot. I now imported the goal from my GA4 property there (even though the goal in google ads says 0 conversion while analytics shows a different number there). Nonetheless, how do I attach that goal to the campaign now so the campaign is optimised for that goal? Going back to the campaign after importing the goal, it doesn't seem to make any changes and I still can't use that goal in the campaign. Any thoughts?

Comment: IIRC, goal completions don't show in Ads immediately. I can't recall if it imports existing goal completion data or if it just logs new conversions. As for applying the goal to a campaign, it will be included among the "other" goals.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins got you, thanks. I can see multiple goals there (in my case it's under "sign up") and the only way to update the campaign goals that I was able to find is if I go to "All Campaigns" -> select my campaign -> press edit -> "update conversion goals" but it only allows to select the whole category of events. How do I select only a specific event under that category? Sorry for all those questions, but it seems like something as simple as using a goal from GA4 is scattered all over google ads dashboard and you need to collect all the pieces before you can use it.

Comment: Change the value of the "Goal and action optimisation" setting in the conversion goal. The default is "other" and the campaign settings use these to group the goals that you can select.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins, ok seems like it's still limited to the "group" rather than an individual event but at least I can see how I can change the group. Thanks a lot for your help. This journey wasn't quite what I was expecting when I created a campaign - it was straightforward to add UA, but GA4 looks a total mess comparing to setting up goals from UA. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help again. If you want to post an answer with any of the comments, I'll accept it right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Conversions in Google Ads, you'll see a list of existing conversions (if you have any) and a button to add new ones (either saying, "+New Conversion Action" or just a + symbol, depending on if you're viewing the Summary page or the All Conversions page).

Clicking that button gives me four choices of type of conversion, the fourth of which is "Import", which then gives an option to import from UA or GA4.[image: Google Ads Add Conversion screen]

Select GA4, and then choose any goals from linked GA4 properties. Once added, make sure you have selected the right "Goal and action optimisation" so that you can use the goal for campaign specific optimisation.

It's also a good idea to make sure you've selected the right Value (if applicable), Count option (either once or every, depending on the value of repeated goals by a single user), and set up the right conversion window and attribution model.